# Dynamically created dropdown doesn't work with selection

Tags: jquery, debugging, drop-down-menu

On my site, I have a input field where users can enter in usernames to add collaborators to a project.  I dynamically create a dropdown list when the user begins typing in a username (using AJAX) so that it fetches potentially registered usernames from the database:

[image]

The HTML for the above dropdown is:

```
<div class="search_results">
    <div class="dropdown open">
        <a class="search_results_toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
           <li class="tiff"><a class="search_result" href="#">tiff</a></li>
           <li class="ttseng"><a class="search_result" href="#">ttseng</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

I thought it would be straightforward to find out which element of the list was selected using something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search_result').click(function(){
      console.log('clicked search result');
      // replace the form with the username
      $(this).closest('form').remove();
      $(this).closest('.user').append($(this).html());
    }); 
});
```

However, I'm finding that with the dynamically created list elements, I'm not able to get any events on them successfully (no console messages are created).  The only thing I find that works is to detect when the user hovers over the $('.dropdown') div, but if I try to detect clicks/hovering over any of its children elements (such as dropdown-menu, li, a etc.), it doesn't work, which I need to find the exact element that's selected.

Is this a known problem with using dynamically created Jquery dropdowns?  How can I fix this?

Comment: delegation is what you are looking for like thousand guys before who have asked similar question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dynamic created elements use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.search_result' ,function(){
```

Comment: You know what's funny, I didn't even know this was a "bug", since I've just always used event delegation. Good answer :P

Comment: wow, thanks a lot!  I didn't know about this.  can you point me to some documentation?

Comment: Note that you should tie the selector you use to as close (in the DOM) to the element as possible, so that it doesn't bubble up every time you click anything on the body.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an issue with your click listener.

Here's what happens :

`$('.search_result')` is (roughly) an array of HTML elements matching this CSS selector.

doing `$('.search_result').click(whatever)` will call `click` on the elements matching this selector *at the time it is created*.

So if you create elements later, they would never have something attached.

What you want to do instead is use `on`'s descendant selector.

```
 $('.search_results').on('click','.search_result',whatever)
```

What happens in this case is that there is only one event listener (on your entire `.search_results` div). When a `click` event is triggered, jQuery checks to see if a descendant `search_result` (the second string) is capable of capturing the event. This will work even when adding new search results: the click event is on the container, after all, so as long as the container exists, this event listener exists.

Actually, even in static situations, using this second form is preferable: in your first one you will create `n` event listeners (1 for each search result), wheras in the second form you only create 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is attaching event listeners to the known .search_result elements when the document is loaded, what you need to do is attach a listener whenever you create the new elements.

Where ever you happen to be calling $('.dropdown-menu').append()  is where you'll need to add the listener.

```
var li = $('<li>test</li>');
li.on('click', function(){
    alert('I was clicked.');
});
$('ul').append(li);
```

Simple example - http://jsfiddle.net/4FPx5/

Comment: This is a bad way to do things. Event delegation, as everyone else answered, is easier to maintain.